# Execute task on Windows startup/shutdown with custom message

Tags: windows, task, message, startup, shutdown

I already know a task can be executed on startup or shutdown by defining the path to the desired script in the group policy editor (gpedit.msc) under

```
Computer Configuration --> Windows settings --> Scripts (Startup/Shutdown).
```

But how is it possible to show a custom progress message on the Windows startup respectively shutdown screen during task execution? For example Windows Update shows the following message when installing updates

```
Configuring Windows updates n% complete.
Do not turn off your computer.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think that windows update is in a privileged position that general code doesn't have access to.

Comment: For example Acronis True Image also shows a custom message on the shutdown screen if a backup task is executed, so it's not only possible by Windows system applications.